# dropdown that filters results in django

Tags: python, django

I would like a basic dropdown box and a submit button on my django page. When the user selects something from the dropdown and hits submit it filters the results. This should be pretty easy, but I have spent hours and can't find an example of what I am trying to do. How do I get the data from POST? Many people suggest not to use the raw POST data and to use form.is_valid() instead, however I am not using a forms.py in this case (not sure I need to use forms.py to use form.is_valid?? Even if I can use forms.is_valid how do I extract what the user selected?).

Here is my views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    plants = Plant.objects.all().order_by('IMS_plant')

    if request.POST:
        #selectedplant = #need to figure out how to get the value from the form in the template
        sightings = Sighting.objects.all().filter(IMS_plant=selectedplant)
        context =  {'sightings':sightings, 'plants': plants}
    else:
        sightings = Sighting.objects.all().order_by('date')    
        context =  {'sightings':sightings, 'plants': plants}

    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is my template

```html
<form action="/dashboard/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <select name="plant">
    <option selected="selected">All Plants</option>
    {% for plant in plants %}
    <option value="{{ plant.IMS_plant }}">{{ plant.IMS_plant }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Select Plant">
</form>
<p>
  {% for sighting in sightings %}
  <a href="/dashboard/sighting/{{ sighting.slug }}/ ">{{ sighting.date|date:"m/d/Y" }} {{ sighting.brand }} ${{ sighting.price|intcomma }} </a>
  <br>{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use django-way. Use forms.

forms.py:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    selectedplant = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Plant.objects.all().order_by('IMS_plant'), required=True)
```

view.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
    form = FilterForm()
    sightings = []
    if request.POST:
        form = FilterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            selectedplant = form.cleaned_data['selectedplant']
            sightings = Sighting.objects.filter(IMS_plant=selectedplant)
        else:
            sightings = Sighting.objects.all().order_by('date')  
    else:
        sightings = Sighting.objects.all().order_by('date')    

    context =  {'sightings':sightings, 'form': form}

    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And then just render {{ form }} in template

Comment: Thanks EvilX this worked out pretty well, I had to make a few small changes to get things just the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked EvilX's solution a bit so that there was an option to "Show All".

forms.py

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    selectedplant = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Plant.objects.all().order_by('IMS_plant'), required=False, label='', empty_label="Show All")
```

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    form = FilterForm()
    sightings = []
    if request.POST:
        form = FilterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            selectedplant = form.cleaned_data['selectedplant']
            if selectedplant == None:
                sightings = Sighting.objects.all().order_by('date')
            else:
                sightings = Sighting.objects.filter(IMS_plant=selectedplant)            
        else:
            sightings = Sighting.objects.all().order_by('date')  
    else:
        sightings = Sighting.objects.all().order_by('date')    

    context =  {'sightings': sightings, 'form': form}

    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This works pretty well, although I am not thrilled with the fact that `sightings = Sighting.objects.all().order_by('date')` appears 3 times in the code, but it isn't the end of the world (just wish it looked a little cleaner).

Thanks again EvilX!

Answer (score -1):

The [Django-filter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-filter) app does exactly what you want. If you were more interested in implementation than the feature then a look at the [source code](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) should be instructive.